# is res-type required for JNDI setup in web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi

I met the situation that JNDI provider on different application servers might have different proxy interface/class(like in JMS, Websphere may have `javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory` instead of `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory`), so in web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>JNDI for jms access</description>
    <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Is the `<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>` must defined to make everything works?

I think the JNDI name should be fine as it should be unique in the initial context?

I do find [something](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4721/beaww/index.html) from Oracle but not sure it is official?

Answer (score 0):

From the EE platform spec (emphasis mine):

> The res-type element is **optional if an injection target is specified**
>   **for this resource**; in this case the res-type defaults to the type of
>   the injection target.

I believe `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` should also work on WebSphere Application Server if some other application server requires a different value.